# Close lots of holes with "virtual duct tape" or by "balloon inflating"

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a mesh (one object) that I created by unifying a lot of other objects (Boolean Modifier). However, the modifier did not quite worked out on some places which leaves me with a mesh with a lot of holes.

These holes are not always just simple edge loops and there are a *lot* of them. Here are two examples:
[image: mesh with holes, example 1]
[image: mesh with holes, example 2]
These are only parts of the object. The shape of the whole object is somewhat similar to a bucket (with a lot of holes).

Is there a way to close these holes in a simple way? It ist not really relevant to close them nicely, they should just be closed.

When I would have such a mesh in reality with something like paper, I would simply duct tape those holes. Or, another way: Put a balloon inside the mesh/bucket and inflate it (similar to a bicycle tire, where the inner tube fills the casing). Is there an equivalent for these techniques in Blender?

**Edit:** Following the comments, I want to give some more details about the model. First, I want to make a house out of cookies. The result should be 3D printed. Therefore, I have a base mesh ([from Thingiverse/phrxmd](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4234703)) of a cookie which I piled up (I intentionally did this manually like I would pile it up in the real world by hand). Then, I wanted to merge all these cookies together with an underlying base mesh into one object to be able to print this properly. I did this with the Boolean modifier. However, it does not work out quite well:

1. Sometimes the "Union" operation did a "Difference" and vice versa.
2. Sometimes the inner geometry of the cookie was not removed very well.
3. It was impossible to union all cookies at once with the cube (Boolean Modifier → Union → With Collection) since it ate *a lot of* RAM (>60GB).

So I did this partially (unify a bunch of cookies into bigger objects and unify this with the cube, manually removed the inner geometry) and got the geometry in the pictures above.

To demonstrate the whole process, I have attached a model that is simpler than the original one but should show the problem:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello it's hard to guess your topology, maybe share the object itself, but I guess it will be easier to model it again

Comment: You can fill the holes in Edit Mode (select 2 Edges, then press F). This will be a pain. Also painful: Shrinkwrap Modifier on a large subdivided quad sphere... Also painful: inflate a cloth simulation system. I'm afraid moonboots is right: it would be best to watch some topology and general modeling tutorials and then start over again.

Comment: Have to agree with @moonboots.. if you can clue us in to the  desired _result_ , then maybe one of us can come up with another way of modelling it.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post according to your comments.